# Response from a Flow in PowerApps returns a type Blob instead of JSON

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I have a PowerApp with a button that triggers a flow:

[image: Flow]

The button content is a function:
`Set(myVar, myFlow.Run())`

Looking in Monitor I see that the response that is returned, looks good:

```
...
    "response": {
      "body": {
        "items": "Test 123"
      },
      "responseType": "json"
    }
...
```

But when I want to use the variable 'myVar' (for which it says is of type 'Record'), the only available property is named 'json' with a type 'Blob' which makes it unusable.

Does anybody know why it creates the variable with a type 'Blob' or how to change that back to a normal JSON object that I can use the 'items' property of?

Answer (score 0):

Using a TextBox control, set the `Default` property to `myVar.` (Notice the `.`!) Set the value to whatever is displayed in the intellisense.

This is called using "dot notation".

If that doesn't work, try setting the `Default` property of the TextBox to `First(myVar).Value` (or whatever intellisense says to call the suffix).